# Laravel, where to place the logic for the app.blade.php file?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 for my new project and I want to follow best practices. I have my layout wrapper as `resources/views/app.blade.php` and it 'yields' every view. I need to show some dynamically generated data in app.blade.php, where should I place the logic to generate the data? For any other view I would do it in the corresponding controller, but for the whole app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Composers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Users\Repository as UserRepository;

class ProfileComposer {

    /**
     * The user repository implementation.
     *
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Create a new profile composer.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('count', $this->users->count());
    }

}
```

And bind to view!

```
View::composer(['profile', 'dashboard'], 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer');
```